# JQuery GET request not able to submit JSON data for spring controller

Tags: jquery, spring, post, controller, get

I am using Jquery 1.4.4 and Spring 3.0. This is really strange. When I submit AJAX request as GET type the spring controller is not getting invoked. However, for same request when I use POST method the controller gets invoked successfully. There is no other change other than using POST versus GET method. Can someone please help - Am I missing something? This is my JS and controller code.

The URL submitted based on fiddler is:
http://localhost:8680/fxiapi/auth/login?{%22user%22:%22dd%22,%22pass%22:%22ss%22,%22org%22:%22dd%22}

```
        $.ajax({
            url: '/fxiapi/auth/login',
            type: 'GET',
            data: JSON.stringify({"user":uname,"pass":pswd,"org":org}),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
            processData: false,
            beforeSend: function(x) {
                if (x && x.overrideMimeType) {
                    x.overrideMimeType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
                }
            },
            success: function(data) {
                this.authToken = data.authToken;
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('you are not authenticated');
            }
        });

@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public
@ResponseBody
LoginResponse login(@RequestBody LoginRequest loginData, HttpServletResponse response)  {
       return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [HTTP GET with request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body)

Comment: Thanks for pointing to this link. I think I need to use POST for such kind of request.